# GWT: How to serialize objects

Tags: gwt, servlets, serialization

I'd like to know if it is possible to use the serializer of GWT. When using the rpc-mechnism of GWT, GWT serializes the objects on the client and deserializes the objects on the server. For this mechanism you have to use special servlets (`RemoteServiceServlet`) of GWT. But i want to use the normal HttpServlets and therefore i have to serialize and deserialize the objects by myself.

Answer (score 3):

All the code you need to look at is in the [RemoteServiceServlet.java](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/server/rpc/RemoteServiceServlet.java). Focus on the [processCall](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/server/rpc/RemoteServiceServlet.java#184) method.

The [RPC.decodeRequest(payload, ...)](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/server/rpc/RPC.java#225) will give you a RPCRequest object which includes the method to be called and the deserialized parameters.

To encode the response focus on [RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse()](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/server/rpc/RPC.java#549) and [RPC.encodeResponseForSuccess()](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/server/rpc/RPC.java#445) methods.

[EDITED]

In client-side it's worth to take a look to the proxy classes generated by the RPC generator, concretely the `YourService_Proxy.java` file. Generated files are left somewhere in your project's folder structure after compiling a project (you can indicate this folder with the `-gen` though).

The interesting code is in in the [RemoteServiceProxy](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/impl/RemoteServiceProxy.java), looking at the [createStreamWritter](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/impl/RemoteServiceProxy.java#276) method, you can see how to serialize your objects. In the [createStreamReader](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/impl/RemoteServiceProxy.java#255) you can see how to deserialize a message from the server.

Comment: Thank you Manolo. Is it right that i have to decode on the client side with SerializationStreamFactory? How can I create an instance of SerializationStreamFactory?

Comment: Edited my response to include the client side.

Answer (score 0):

See [gwt-byte-serializer](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-byte-serializer/)

```
SerializerInt ser = new Serializer();
ser.writeValue("test");
ser.writeValue(new int[]{5,1,6});

String buffer = ser.getBuffer();

SerializerInt des = new Serializer(buffer);

des.readString()
des.readIntegerArr()
```